# PHP else if statement with multiple functions

Tags: php

So I have a php post process to put user input into a csv. I added in an if/else statement so my headers don't get added every time there is a user submission however now my process won't run. I'm not sure where I'm going wrong as I'm prety new to PHP. The code is below.

```
<?php    
$headers = array('FirstName','LastName','Initials','Number','Department','Password');
$user = array($_POST['firstname'],$_POST['lastname'],$_POST['initials'],$_POST['number'],$_POST['department'],$_POST['password']);
$filename = 'newusers.csv';


$fp = fopen($filename,'a');


$op1 = fputcsv($fp,$headers);
$op2 = fputcsv($fp,$user); //pass $_POST and filehandle to fputcsv

fclose($fp);
if file_exists($filename) {
    fputcsv($fp,$user);
}
else {
    fputcsv($fp,$headers);
    fputcsv($fp,$user);
}

if( $op1 && $op2 ) {
    $redirect = "Location: //redirecthere//";
} else {
    $redirect = "Location: //redirect here//";
}

header($redirect);
die();
?>
```

I think my issue is with the op1 and op2 variables in my redirect statement but I'm unsure. I also wonder if perhaps my else statement is written wrong. Or did I miss a semicolon somewhere? Thanks in advance

Comment: Do not use real values like `IP` in questions.

Comment: Change `if file_exists($filename)` to `if(file_exists($filename))`

Comment: What do you mean with "my process wont run"? Do you see any errors, what do you expect to happen, describe what is actually happening?

Comment: Your code makes no sense. Write your header/data to the file, CLOSE the filehandle, then try to write the exact same stuff to the file you've just closed?

Comment: Woops on the IP thought that was changed. And I was getting a hangup on the process. I didn't get an error statement when it ran.

Comment: @Marc B: It didn't. I've changed quite a bit in the 20 minutes. Finding dumb mistakes here and there. This is first time really working with PHP . Been just gleaning info from my co-worker and researching a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use

```
if (file_exists($filename)) {
```

instead of

```
if file_exists($filename) {
```

Comment: And now I feel like a doofus. Thank you.

Comment: @DarthAbingdon [`Did you not read the 2nd comment`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25749183/php-else-if-statement-with-multiple-functions#comment40262168_25749183)

Answer (score 0):

when you use if you must always have condition inside a bracket
`if file_exists($filename)` should be changed to `if(file_exists($filename))`

Answer (score 0):

I made some modifications. Try it, It should work

```
$user = array($_POST['firstname'],$_POST['lastname'],$_POST['initials'],$_POST['number'],$_POST['department'],$_POST['password']);
$filename = 'newusers.csv';

if (file_exists($filename)) {
    $fp = fopen($filename,'a');
    $ok = fputcsv($fp,$user);
} else {
    $fp = fopen($filename,'w');
    $headers = array('FirstName','LastName','Initials','Number','Department','Password');
    $ok = fputcsv($fp,$headers) && fputcsv($fp,$user);
}

fclose($fp);

if ( $ok ) {
    $redirect = "Location: http://128.222.4.24/custom/owen/success.html";
} else {
    $redirect = "Location: http://128.222.4.24/custom/owen/error.html";
}

header($redirect);
die();
```

Comment: Heh. I had actually just fixed an issue with my code I found after the solution and it was something similiar. Thank you.